# Insert Image into PPT using Standard Libraries

Tags: python, powerpoint

I know this is possible to do using additional libraries such as win32com or python-pptx, but I wasn wondering if anyone knew of a way to insert an image into a powerpoint slide using the standard libraries. Lots of googling has indicated that the best solution is probably win32com, but since I can guarantee that every system this script will be deployed to will have win32com, I am looking for an implemention leveraging libraries all systems with a standard python 2.7 install will have.

Comment: You can do almost *anything* with the Python standard libraries. But this is effectively re-implementing features already found elsewhere, usually with more bugs, less features, less documentation, and which only works in 90% of the cases.

Comment: I'm pretty much with @Carpetsmoker on this one. Of course you can do it, but why would you want to? Can you elaborate a bit on why you have this constraint? I know how to do what you're asking but I can't imagine a situation in which I would undertake to do it.

Comment: I am a GIS programmer and I work for a large financial institution. We support a team market which basically decides where new branches and atms go. In making that decision, they visit a bunch of potential sites. We support that event with ppt packages that detail the demographics for a given site and display all of that information on a map. Naturally, I can export a bunch of map views but getting them into a PPT template was not something I knew how to do right off hand. Now knowing & seeing that PPTX files are just a zipped file with all of the elements and XMLs defining such. It's simple.

Comment: Don't even have to parse the XML. Set up a template PPTX, inserting png files with names that detail exactly what you want them to be. Then change file extension to zip. Swap images in media folder with your new images which have same name as those already in zip file. No need to parse file. XML is already referencing that image. Done.

Comment: @MrbUbbles: No need to "swap the file extension" - it is a zip file, nonetheless, when you are open it programatically. Windows' sickly file-name based forced type recognition is just broken. Of course, if you are on windows, and want to open the file in a UI program you have to resort to that - but using Python there is no need too. And...if one is to manually manipulte the files, he'd be better using powerpoint or libreoffice to startwith.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is probably possible to modify a `.pptx` file with the standard library without much effort: these new generation of files are meant to be zip-compressed XML + external images files, and can be handled by `ziplib` and standard xml parsers.

Legacy `.ppt` files however are a binary closed format, with little documentation, and hundrededs of corner cases. It would alwasys "be possible"  to change them, since they are still just bytes, but it would take considerable effort.

That said, starting with Python 3.4, the Python installer "PIP" comes default with the language install: probably the best way to go would be to script the installation of external libraries based on the built-in PIP - that way one would not have to all external library usage.

Comment: Thanks JS, i'll tinker with some pptx files. We have to stick with python 2.x series due to compatibility an API compatibility that will probably never hit Python 3. Perhaps distutils can help here too.

If anyone has an example of manipulating a pptx file, no matter how basic, I'd really appreciate an example